# d3 change position of pie chart (middle point)

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, gauge

Is there a way to change the position of a pie chart in D3 ?
It seems I can only set the inner and outer Radius not the center.
I want to draw another cicle around my donut chart (gauge) but it doesn't fit now.
In IE it looks ok though, so it might also be an browser bug.
Any help is appreciated, I am quit new to html/d3/javascript.

I made a fiddle of my code :
https://jsfiddle.net/mistert69/nz0tvq24/3/

no center of radius ? :

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
    .outerRadius(outerRadius);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .startAngle(-120 * (pi / 180))
    .endAngle(120 * (pi / 180));
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. But you can easily move your pie chart by appending it to a group that's shifted: `var g = svg.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(40, 40)'`. That would move the pie chart 40 pixels down and 40 pixels to the right. Of course, you'd have to change the SVG width and height a corresponding amount to keep the pie chart the same size.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can translate the group containing the pie chart by using attr('transform', 'translate(x, y)'.

There is no other way to position the pie chart in d3.

Comment: Yes, thanks that solved my problem !  I can now shift my arc's and match the circles around them.